# slow sql oledb connection

Tags: sql-server, oledb

Can someone tell me why the code below performs very slow?
The last sentence takes more than 6 seconds.
I am trying to read data from a SQL server with C++.

```
std::string connectString("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=YYY;Integrated Security=SSPI;"); 
_ConnectionPtr Connection; 
CoInitialize(NULL); 
pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection)); 
HRESULT hr=Connection->Open(connectString.c_str(),"","",adConnectUnspecified);
```

Comment: How long would you expect it to take (6 seconds sounds like a very long time)? Could the database be loading?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the portnumber did the trick!

std::string connectString("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=XXX,1430;Initial Catalog=YYY;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points to check:

- Between your datasource and your application lies a **network connection**, e.g. a SMB share. These tend to be slow.
- Try to find out if some **registry settings** work against you, forcing too small net packets or other kinds of throttles. These things depend on the framework version.
- A **virus scanner** wants to be your friend.
- Here is an example how the **firewall** can disturb: [Very slow connection to SQL Server 2005 only if using ADO.NET with SqlClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178931/very-slow-connection-to-sql-server-2005-only-if-using-ado-net-with-sqlclient)
  As the firewall blocks the requests, the system chooses some pipe streaming after a timeout.

I hope one of those will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to enable TCP/IP using Sql Server Configuration Manager (I'm not sure how it managed to connect before; only Shared Memory was enabled ¯\_ (ツ)_/¯ )